# Non-linear deformation of a plot image to achieve true logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, logarithm

While trying to digitize a legacy figure, I discovered that its logarithmic scale is deformed and does not match the true logarithmic scale (red crosses) on both X- and Y-axes:

[image: ---]

[Left-most part of the original figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tq4i.png)

Therefore there is a need to deform the image to achieve a true logarithmic scale. What is the best way to do this using MATLAB?

Comment: Looks to me that the bottom of the scale is not 0.1, maybe more like 1.13. The scale looks like a fine logarithmic scale to me.

Comment: It looks like, but in the original publication the bottom of the scale is 0.1. Please see added picture of original plot.

Comment: I don’t believe so. Try changing the bottom limit and you’ll see that the tick marks line up nicely.

Comment: Please see the part of the original image below.
I think this is a log-like scale :)

Comment: Andy, it is really obvious that the 0.1 is mislabeled. The distance between 0.1 and 0.2 should be the same as between 1 and 2. || Note that you can [edit] your question at any time to add details and improve it. The box below is for answering the question only.

Comment: Dear Cris, thank for the suggestion - I moved the item to the original question. Coming back to the topic: this figure was taken from a research article and if I got no solid proof that the scale is bad I would assume that the image was badly deformed during scanning or somehow else. Can you suggest a way to deform the image to achieve a full match to a true logarithmic scale using MATLAB, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have generated a logarithmic axis in Octave, then in Gimp I overlaid your original graph and scaled it so that its y-axis matches the one I created in Octave. The result is at the bottom of this post.

As you can see, the axes match perfectly. The plot contains a correct logarithmic axis and does not need to be corrected in any way.

There is a lost "0.1" label at the bottom of the axis, that doesn't correspond to a visible tick mark. The most likely explanation for this is an error by the person that created the graph. This label should simply be ignored. The actual 0.1 tick mark should be a little further down, outside of the graph area.

[image: OP's original plot overlaid on computer-generated logarithmic axes]

Comment: Cris, you've got a good eye! Thank you very much for figuring this out!